# How do I exclude pixels whose neighbours are out of the image borders?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I need to compute the neighbours of several points in an image, after which I would do some other stuff with what I get. I am however worried about the possibility of non-existence of some of the neighbours of some of these points.
I know I could pad the borders of my image by adding extra pixels, however I do not intend to employ that approach because of the nature of what I am trying to do. I am looking for a means via which I could test to see if all 5x5 connected neighbours surrounding each of these points exist, otherwise I would want to ignore that particular point if any part of its 5x5 immediate neighbour pixels are out of the borders.

To make this a bit more clearer I have included the code below:

```
img = [2 2 2 2 2 2 2;
       2 3 2 2 2 2 2;
       2 2 2 0 2 2 2;
       4 4 1 2 2 2 2;
       4 4 0 4 4 0 4;
       4 1 1 4 4 4 4;
       1 1 1 4 4 4 4];

[nrow, ncol]     = find(img == 0)

P_Idx            = sub2ind(size(img), nrow, ncol);

M                = size(img, 1);

neighbor_offsets = [-M-1, -M, -M+1, -1, 1, M-1, M, M+1];

if any of the 5x5 immediate neighbours of Point P are outside the image borders, 
       Then ignore that particular point P, 

else 
      find the neighbours as follows:

     %Compute the immediate neighbors of ‘P’
     P_neighbors       = bsxfun(@plus, P_Idx, neighbor_offsets);

     Do the following…

end
```

Comment: If you're not padding the matrix then the only option will be to start the loop after the first 2 rows and first 2 columns. This actually reduces the image size by 4 rows and 4 columns, but there is no way around it. The actual image in your example will be the center highlighted pixels here (http://i.imgur.com/FNvMlV9.jpg). 
This is normal  for filtering in image processing.

Comment: Another option is to test `if x >= 2 and x < w-2 and y >= 2 and y < h-2`.

Comment: Another option is to clamp the coordinates that you process as `min(max(x, 0), w-1), min(max(y, 0), h-1)`. This is different in that it allows to process all pixels as if all neighbors were there, by replicating the pixels on the sides.

Comment: You also have the options of creating artificial pixel values as a constant, by mirroring or by tiling the plane (`x mod w, y mod h`).